# Failing to change the text of a label - any idea why?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to change the text of a label in a piece of C# code activated by a button on the main page. Having looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916684/c-net-change-label-text), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445120/append-text-to-label-in-asp-net-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445120/append-text-to-label-in-asp-net-c) I understand that setting the text value as I do in this way...

```
try
{
    mylabel.Text = "";
    do_foo (blah);
}
catch (myexception ex)
{
    mylabel.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

should produce the error message I'm looking for. But in spite of the fact that stepping through the code shows that both the assignments are executed, the label text remains unchanged.

Does anyone have any idea what I could try, either to make this work or to find out why it isn't working?

**EDIT** Some more details as asked (thanks for your help so far, chaps).

The ASP.NET page has the following parts. The button is defined like this:-

```
<div class="section3Header">
    <span class="heading1">Some Heading</span>
    <input id="Button2" class="button2" type="button" value="Do Work" onclick="do_work();" />
</div>
```

The button activates some Javascript:

```
  function do_work() {
     CallBackOU.callback("Do Work");
  }
```

and that calls the C# code:

```
protected void CallBackOU_Callback( object sender, ComponentArt.Web.UI.CallBackEventArgs e )
{
    if      (e.Parameter == "Do Work")
    {
        this.CallBackOUHelper_Do_Work (e.Output);
    }

}
```

and that calls the function:

```
private void CallBackOUHelper_Do_Work (HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    try
    {
        mylabel.Text = "";
        do_foo (blah);
    }
    catch (myexception ex)
    {
        mylabel.Text = ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

There is a good deal more code in the project than this, obviously, but I can't include it all and am not sure which bits are important.

**EDIT 2** The button activating the code is inside a `ComponentArt:CallBack`. Studying the documentation for this product [here](http://docs.componentart.com/#UIFramework/2011/ComponentArt.Web.UI.AJAX.client/ComponentArt.Web.UI~CallBack_class.htm) leads me to suspect this may be the problem; if parts of the screen outside this object are not posted back, naturally the labels (outside) would be unchanged.

Comment: what does the label text say?

Comment: @Tim B, the label is set in the form to say "Label", just so I can see where it is until I can get this to work.

Comment: Where is this executed? Eg in or before Form_Load?

Comment: Try adding a second label to the page and assign the `ex.ToString()` to this one. Rule out that at least you can change the text of a label

Comment: @Henk, after form_load. The user sets some values and clicks the Go button; this code is in the callback for that button.

Comment: Is this code in your `Page_Load` event? If not, when is it being ran?

Comment: @Brain Hooper - Have you tried debugging? Does the button click event get ran? Perhaps it hasn't been called correctly? Could you post more code?

Comment: @Tim B, I have added more code; thanks for your effosts so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created your scenario in my PC and its working fine.
But if you are using AJAX then it will completely depends on your implementation of Update panel.

If label is not in update panel and button is on update panel then button click event will not update label text until unless you add handler on its click event.

So please provide complete scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your help; I have added more code to the question.

Comment: Following up your lead, I found the problem was caused by the `ComponentArt:CallBack` controls inside the page; one must include any control one wishes to update inside the same callback block.

Answer (score -2):

If it is still busy processing after this, perhaps it is not updating the GUI immediately. Try calling `Refresh()` on the form after updating.

Comment: I made the same mistake when I read his post. I think he's talking about ASP.NET as his tag suggests, not Windows Forms.